# IOS 5.1 Backup / Restore App file from Documents Directory to / from iCloud

Tags: ios, ipad, sdk, icloud

I have created a database (IOS 5.1) with XCode 4.3.3 for the iPad and have set it up so that the user can backup and restore the database file (*.sqlite) to DropBox. Everything works fine...

Now I would like to do the same process but, set it up for iCloud. Looking for the following function:

1. Tap a button to backup the *.sqlite file from the Apps Document Directory up to iCloud at users preference.
2. Tap a button to copy the *.sqlite file down from iCloud to the Apps Document Directory.

I have been struggling trying to find the solution, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For moving any file to and from icloud you can use this code below.

```
[[[NSFileManager alloc]init] setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:your iCloudURL destinationURL:localDirectoryURL error:&errorsss];
```

only thing is if you are moving to icloud the code should be :

```
[[[NSFileManager alloc]init] setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:localDirectoryURL destinationURL:your_iCloudURL error:&errorsss];
```

and if you are getting it from iCloud to Apps Documents directory

```
[[[NSFileManager alloc]init] setUbiquitous:NO itemAtURL:your_iCloudURL destinationURL:localDirectoryURL error:&errorsss];
```