# How to  take backup of documents in iCloud?

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

Hi i am new in iPhone development.In my app I want to take backup of my app documents in iCloud so that the app can be restored from the iCloud if the user uninstall the app.But I didn't find any sample code of taking back and restore from the backup.Can any one suggest me a solution to achieve this.I have one more question,is there any limitations in iCloud backup ?

Comment: Check this link 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083327/ios-5-1-backup-restore-app-file-from-documents-directory-to-from-icloud/17540507#17540507